# django DetailView url hiding pk

Tags: django

//i have a detailview in Django

```
http://www.test.nl/detail_view/1/
```

//is there a way to hide the /1/ in the url so users don't see that?

Comment: Try sending the `variable` 1 using forms. By submitting the form, the view gets the variable 1 instead of getting it from urls

Comment: would a slug field be what you are looking for ?   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#slugfield

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you need to specify another way to uniquely identify your model instance. Commonly used for this are: [SlugField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) or [UUIDField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield).

You should therefore modify your models to include one of those (or any other field that you can ensure to be unique for that matter) and then override your model's save method as required, so that the field is populated correctly.

Finally, you will need to also modify your urls.py to parse your unique field and not the default that you want to hide (pk)

e.g.

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path('detail_view/<slug:slug>/', views.detail_view),
]
```

Comment: tx for the answers but i want no id after the detail. I think however this is not possible .

Comment: Well, then no it is not. If you want the server to return a detail page, the browser has to somehow precise which detail page...

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve? If you explain your use case better, maybe we can find a solution. But using the standard detail view request cycle as specified in your question this is not possible.